# JQuery toggle other row when one selected and change the text

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

earlier sorry if my english bad

I have problem with toggle other row, i want to choose one row and the other row is hide.
When the choosen row selected, i want to change the div from choose to cancel (like if one button clicked, show the other button with the value cancel). And if i click the cancel button, it back to earlier.
Hidding the other row is success, but the changing div/button/etc is the main problem.
Please anyone know the solution?

Thank you before.

Here the html

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="choose"><a href="#" class="pick">Choose 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cancel" hidden><a href="#" class="poke">Cancel 1</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="choose"><a href="#" class="pick">Choose 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cancel" hidden><a href="#" class="poke">Cancel 1</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="choose"><a href="#" class="pick">Choose 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cancel" hidden><a href="#" class="poke">Cancel 3</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the JQuery code i write

```
$('.pick').click(function () {
$(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr').toggle('slow');});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood what you're trying to do, if not, please let me know.

You need to add code that hides the "choose" button from the current row, and un-hide the cancel button container.

```
$('.pick').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr').toggle('slow');
    $(this).parent().toggle();           // Hide the "choose" button container
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();    // Show the "cancel" button container
});
```

You also need to make the "cancel" button return everything to the initial state, like this:

```
$('.poke').click(function () {
    $('tr').show();         // Show all table rows
    $('.choose').show();    // Show all the "choose" button containers
    $('.cancel').hide();    // Hide all the "cancel" button containers
});
```

Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/VRAa9/4/

Comment: Wow, thank you that's working now. But can i ask about "parent()"? What this function in code above?

Comment: .parent() returns the element that directly contains the current matched element. For example, in your HTML code, the parent of `<a href="#" class="pick">Choose 1</a>` is `<div class="choose"></div>`. Here's the documentation of .parent() on the jQuery website: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: oh, i see, so the "parent()" this is take the previous tag? really?

Comment: The *previous* as in one level up in the DOM tree, yes. It basically gives you the element that *contains* the selected element.

Comment: can i ask again, when i have two table same i try to hide/show again like before, it's not working just add the same jquery with different selector...can you help me again?

Comment: here is it [http://jsfiddle.net/fW8AL/](http://jsfiddle.net/fW8AL/) when i think i can just use two selector different, but its not right

Comment: In the second table, `<a>Cancel 5</a>` and `<a>Cancel 6</a>` should have the class `poke2` not `poke`.

Comment: sorry i forgot that, but when in the second table all class change to `choose2`, `cancel2`, `pick2`, `poke2`, yes it was hide well one row each table, but when toggle back

Comment: Replace `$('tr').show();` with `$(this).closest('tbody').children().show();` in the cancel click handler.